# Help to call overloaded insertion operator

Tags: operator-overloading

I tried calling my overloaded inserter but it's not doing what it's supposed to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SortedLinkedListInt.h"
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//CONSTRUCTOR
SortedLinkedListInt::SortedLinkedListInt(){
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;   
}

//DESTRUCTOR
SortedLinkedListInt::~SortedLinkedListInt(){    
    while (head != NULL) {
        Node* ptr = head;
        head = head -> next;
        delete ptr;     
    }

}
//COPY CONSTRUCTOR
SortedLinkedListInt::SortedLinkedListInt(const SortedLinkedListInt &obj){
    for(Node* n = obj.head; n!=NULL; n=n->next)
        add(n->data);
}

void SortedLinkedListInt::add(int newElement){  
    if (head == NULL){
        head = new Node;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->data = (newElement);
    }
    else if(head->data > newElement){
        Node* node1 = new Node;
        node1->data = newElement;
        node1->next = head;
        head = node1;
    }
    else{
        Node* node2;
        for(node2=head; node2->next!= NULL; node2 = node2->next)
            if(node2->next->data > newElement)
                break;

        Node* node = new Node;  
        node->next = (node2->next);
        node->data = (newElement);
        node2->next = (node);
        ++size;
    }

}

bool SortedLinkedListInt::exists (int element){
    for (Node* n = head; n != NULL; n = n -> next) // how to write n.getElement() in c++
        if(element == n->data) //analogous to compareTo (java)
            return true;
    return false;
}

void SortedLinkedListInt::toString(){
    for (Node* n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next){
        cout << n->data << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";

}

void SortedLinkedListInt::operator <<(const int &sub){
    add(sub);
    for (Node* n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next){
        cout << n->data << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

The function is at the bottom of the above header file. Below is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SortedLinkedListInt.h"
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    SortedLinkedListInt *sll = new SortedLinkedListInt();
    //SortedLinkedList <int> *sll = new SortedLinkedList<int>;
    /*SortedLinkedList<int> sll2 = *sll;*/


    sll->add(5);
    sll->add(1);
    sll->add(3);
    sll->add(9);
    sll->add(2);
    sll->add(5);

    cout << 5;
    cout << 3;

    //sll->toString();

    int n = 4;

    printf("%d does%s exist in list.\n", n, sll->exists(n) ? "": " not");


    system("PAUSE");

}
```

cout << 5 or any number wont call the overloaded insertion operator. I wanted to have it do the same function as sll->(5). So instead of using sll->(x) all that will be done is cout << x;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but

cout << 5

calls the insertion operator of cout standard stream. If you want to call your own insertion operator at least left part of the statement must be your class.
I hope this helps.